# A difficulty in understanding a step in finding all irreducible representations of $S_{3}.$

Tags: representation-theory

Here is a part of the proof:

[image]

But I do not understand why to find sub-representations it is enough subspaces of V invariant under the action of both $\sigma $ and $\tau$? ...... could anyone explain this for me please ? is it a theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, since $S_3$ is generated by $\sigma$ and $\tau$, we can write any element of $S_3$ as $\sigma^{a_1} \tau^{b_1} \cdots \sigma^{a_n} \tau^{b_n}$ for some integers $a_1, b_1, \ldots, a_n, b_n$. In fact, for $S_3$ we can write any element as $\sigma^a \tau^b$ for some $a, b, but that's not necessary for our purposes.

Now, suppose that $\sigma, \tau$ preserve $V$. Then, for any $v \in V$, $\tau \cdot v \in V$, and thus $\sigma \cdot (\tau \cdot v) \in V$. But by definition of a representation, this is just $(\sigma \tau) \cdot v$. But there's nothing special about the particular product $\sigma \tau$ here---the same argument applies just as well to any other product of $\sigma$ and $\tau$.

Comment: but what is the word sub-representation here mean and why to find them ......?

Comment: does this mean we are finding invariant subspaces of $V$?

Comment: Yes.$\!\!\!\!\!$

Comment: could you please write the powers of $\sigma$ and $\tau$ in numbers ? as an example  ..... as I think my difficulty in understanding is here .... how is a group can be generated by 2 elements .... are $a_{1} \neq a_{n}$ or they can be the same? ....are $a_{1} \neq b_{1}$ or they can be the same?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, but, for example, $\sigma \tau \sigma$ is another such element. Here, $\sigma \tau = (123) (12) = (13)$.

Comment: okay I think it is better if I post another question about this difficulty later ...... by the way thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome, I hope I was able to help some.

Comment: you helped me a lot thank you.